# A word for debates or arguments that started as a result of miscommunication or misinterpretation

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word or succinct phrase for debates or arguments that started as a result of miscommunication or misinterpretation?

Comment: "the internet"?   More seriously, I know just what you mean and I wish there was a SW for this!  There's the phrase "the whole thing was just a mix-up" which is somewhat related.

Comment: More detail, please. See [this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/7709/142322) and [that](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: Related: [What is a word for the sensation when during a conversation you realize you were both talking about different things?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131535/what-is-a-word-for-the-sensation-when-during-a-conversation-you-realize-you-were)

Answer (score 3):

A common phrase to sum up such a situation would be:

> ***'To get your wires crossed'***

A suitable idiom for a misunderstanding especially based off communication. The origins is from telephone comms when people used to hear other phone conversations back in the early/mid 1900s.

Comment: There's also [talking at cross purposes](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22talking+at+cross+purposes%22), which I doubt has its origins in unreliable telephony.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get the ball rolling,

> groundless

"The whole yelling match with my husband was groundless - he actually said my new hairdo makes me like *bold*. Imagine!"

Answer (score 0):

Some of this idea is conveyed with "talking past each other". But that phrase doesn't emphasize the argument so much as the ongoing disjuncture. Your question suggests a premise was misconstrued moreso than an ongoing confusion over the matter at hand.

Comment: While this is true, it is more of a comment on an existing answer than an answer in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talking_past_each_other): *talking past each other*.

> **Talking past each other** is an English phrase meaning two or more people talking about different subjects, while they believe that they are talking about the same thing.

The erroneous belief that they are "talking about the same thing" counts as *miscommunication or misinterpretation* that can easily lead to *debates or arguments*.

The phrase *talking past each other* refers to the debate or argument.