# What is the name, if any, of the act of equating two distinct definitions of the same word?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sorry if this question does not fit this site. If it doesn't please let me know a better place to ask it.

Suppose Alice and Bob have a dialogue:

> Alice: "I don't believe computers can write a story."
>
> Bob: "Yes they can, you can create the program 'print("once upon a time...")' and the computer will write a story.

Now Alice and Bob's usages of the word "write" are distinct. Alice meant to create a story, like what a human author does, while Bob meant to physically mark down words which form a story, like what an inkjet printer does. Therefore they are talking at cross purposes. Is there a word or phrase to describe what Bob is doing, more specific than simply "misunderstanding"?

Comment: I don't think Bob is unintentionally using the *literal* meaning of *write*, so I wouldn't  call this talking at cross purposes.

Comment: Erm... what's wrong with saying they're "talking at cross purposes"? But in your example, Alice & Bob aren't ***equating*** their two different "definitions" - each of them is simply ***using*** their own definition of "to write a story" (and one or both of them is refusing to negotiate a "common" definition that they can both agree on).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nothing is wrong with it, I was just asking if there is a more specific term. "Cross purposes" just means any misunderstanding right? Not necessarily one of the kind I described. And I guess you're right that "equating" was the wrong word to use here.

Comment: 79037662 - You haven't explicitly said whether Bob (who seems to be adopting the "least likely" interpretation) truly believes he's working with the ***default definition*** of the words in play here. If so, they're talking at cross purposes. If not, he's being pointlessly / pedantically ***literal-minded*** - playing "word games" rather than using language to communicate effectively.

Comment: "If people are at cross-purposes, they do not understand each other because they are working toward or talking about different things **without realizing it.**" [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/at-cross-purposes). In this case, I think they understand each other but disagree on the meaning of a word or whether the word can be used to cover the meaning *to compose*.

Comment: [*If people are **at cross-purposes**, they do **not understand each other** because they are working towards or **talking about different things** without realizing it.*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-cross-purposes) And once it's "particularised" as ***talking** at cross purposes*, this nearly always implies *lacking common agreement  on what certain expressions mean*.

Comment: I don't agree. In many cases once the misunderstanding in cross purposes is resolved, there may be agreement.

Comment: If deliberate and intended to deceive, this is [wilful misinterpretation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/568952/idiom-for-someone-who-intentionally-changes-your-words-in-the-way-he-wants/568954#568954). If deliberate and done for more benign reasons, perhaps in jest, this is a play on words. If unintentionally using different definitions, they are certainly [talking at cross purposes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131535/what-is-a-word-for-the-sensation-when-during-a-conversation-you-realize-you-were/131613#131613), leading to a misunderstanding that needs resolving.

Comment: The 'best' answers given at the cited duplicate answer this question better than that.